# Create single value filter to select multiple values

Tags: filter, conditional-statements, tableau-api

If I have a discrete numeric dimension. Can I setup a single value filter to select n AND n-1 at the same time?

Use case: I have events with a running event number and I would like to display the value for any chosen event as well as the previous event.
In the attached workbook, I would like to display events 5 and 6 when selecting just 6.

It is easily possible with the use of a parameter, however since they are not dynamic, it needs to be updated after each new event which I would like to avoid.

[Sample Workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/362aidrvyj7nrck/EventValues.twbx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think the answer is no. Without modifying the data structure you need to use parameters.

[Not an answer, but it might give you some ideas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KmYx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, couldn't this be accomplished with a parameter and calculated field?

1. Setup parameter (PARAMETER 1) to be FIELD1 (int) - assume values 1 to 10
2. Setup calculated field (Calculated Field 1):

IF ([PARAMETER 1] = [Field 1]) OR ([PARAMETER 1] = [Field 1] - 1)THEN 'YES'
ELSE 'NO'
END

3. Add Calculated Field 1 to filters, set to 'YES'
4. Add parameter to worksheet, filter by parameter

[Additional Reading](https://www.interworks.com/blog/rcurtis/2016/05/26/tableau-deep-dive-parameters-calculated-fields)

Comment: Yes, that's possible. However I look for a different way as parameters have certain disadvantages, as written in my question.